# Are 'style/approach review' questions acceptable?

Tags: discussion

This is related to [an earlier question on code review at CV](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/can-code-review-be-relevant-here).

While 'code review' itself is understandably out of scope, I wonder about questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074240/methodology-of-high-dimensional-data-structuring-in-r-vs-matlab) which I asked on SO, and [this question on plotting nicely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714677/r-scatterplot-with-too-many-points).

I imagine that there is a methodological gradient that goes from theory to programming mechanics, but I'm curious where CV stops. [This answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1782/20307) seems particularly salient.

Here are some examples of possible edge cases I thought up and the site they border on:

1. Plotting results effectively ("data-to-ink" ratio) -- SO, TeX?
2. Keeping data organized throughout scaling and transformations (for example, keeping track of categorical variables so they still match the transformed features) -- SO
3. Extending existing statistical packages without creating kludge (both etiquette and methodology here) -- SO
4. Implementation of a stochastic algorithm (is this the right way to code this, or is there a better algebraic expression for X?) -- MSE
5. Reporting results in limited space; how to prioritize? (i.e., papers etc.) -- Academia
6. Preparing chains of statistical analysis elements so that reports can be made mostly agnostic to input data -- SO
7. What's the best way to store data you're going to start/continue analysis work on in `<this language>`? -- SO
8. Basic checklist of "things to try" on data when exploring/classifying (CW) -- SO
9. If I want to do X, when should I format my data like A? If I'm trying to do Y, should I transform my data to B? What's the best way to go about that in `<this language>`? -- SO

These are all methodological questions, and I'd like to ask some of them, in fact. I'd like these questions to be allowable in the context of **review** specifically, because that's really the best way to learn.

Comment: (1.) strikes me as clearly on-topic here. (Regarding your SO post on scatterplots w/ many points, you may be interested in this CV thread: [More efficient plot functions in R when millions of points are present](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7348/).)

Comment: Many of these edge cases would be acceptable here, especially if couched in a way that exhibited their general interest to a community of statisticians and data miners.  The ones that definitely are not on topic here have nicely been flagged already by "<this language>": when a question is language-specific, it almost surely ought to be on SO instead of here.

Comment: Maybe, but I feel like if you're a statistician you're probably used to 'flat' 2D tables for most work, whereas algebraists and engineers do a lot with variable dimension 'cubic' matrices; why and what merits those approaches provide was not really addressed in the question I asked on SO (due to SO's scope).

Comment: I think the key is how much statistical knowledge is needed. I think that, among moderators, I am for a more inclusive approach here. But the guidelines apply to all.